# React JS inview event

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs

How do i add *inview* event in **React JS**?
Something like this:

> `<div inview={handleInView}></div>`

I need to add it on the Footer so i can load more news in page.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind a scroll event and test for the element's position that can alter the state of the component or trigger any other methods/events you need.

I have used jQuery here for the example for simplicity, by targeting the element with a ref, but it would be possible to do this without.
React has some built in scroll stuff they cover them here http://blog.vjeux.com/2013/javascript/scroll-position-with-react.html. Note: the link is quite old so I'm sure there is better docs out there.

```
var Component = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      text: 'Not in view'
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    $(window).on('scroll', this.inview);
  },
  inview: function () {

    var $e = $( React.findDOMNode(this.refs.footer) ),
        $w = $( window ),
        wt = $w.scrollTop(),
        wb = wt + $w.height(),
        et = $e.offset().top,
        eb = et + $e.height();

    var isVisible = eb >= wt && et <= wb;

    this.setState({'text': isVisible ? 'In view' : 'Not in view'});
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.text}</h1>
        <p>Scroll down</p>
        <footer ref="footer">FOOTER</footer>
       </div>
    )
  }
});

React.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

link to see it working in JSBIN [here](http://jsbin.com/vocewiyolo/edit?js,output)

Comment: Not to worry, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a component like this recently. It triggers the `onFetch` prop (specified by a higher order component) when it comes in view.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { debounce } from 'underscore';

export default class ScrollLoader extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.scrollListener = debounce(this.fetchInView.bind(this), 200);
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollListener);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollListener);
    }

    fetchInView() {
        const { loading, onFetch } = this.props;
        const { top } = findDOMNode(this).getBoundingClientRect();
        const OFFSET = 50; // ensure the element is at least 50 pixels in view

        if (!loading && top < window.innerHeight + OFFSET && typeof onFetch === 'function') {
            onFetch();
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { loading } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className={classNames('scrollloader', { 'scrollloader-loading' : loading })} />
        );
    }

}

ScrollLoader.propTypes = {
    loading: PropTypes.bool,
    onFetch: PropTypes.func
};
```